# How can I tweak this camelCase regex to allow for acronyms?

Tags: regex

edit: strictly speaking, they are not acronyms but you get what I mean.

I have found this resource very helpful, https://newbedev.com/regex-for-pascalcased-words-aka-camelcased-with-leading-uppercase-letter but what if I need to tweak the lower camel case version to allow a set of initials to be used in the middle of a name. For example, the author provides a regex for lower camel case, [a-z]+((\d)|([A-Z0-9][a-z0-9]+))*([A-Z])?, which would match the following words:

```
xmlHttpRequest
newCustomerId
innerStopwatch
supportsIpv6OnIos
youTubeImporter
youtubeImporter
affine3D
```

but what about;

```
xmlHTTPRequest
```

where the capialized string features in the middle of the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use this version, which allows for multiple capital letters:

```regex
[a-z0-9]+(?:[A-Z0-9]+[a-z0-9]*)*
```

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/NpwFzO/1) showing that the pattern is working for you new edge case.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood you correct you just have to add a + after [A-Z0-9] like this:

```
[a-z]+((\d)|([A-Z0-9]+[a-z0-9]+))*([A-Z])?
```

https://regex101.com/r/ONgcrA/1

Comment: +1 for the very useful link. Also, that solution works, but it was simply the same as was commented above.[I am referring to a since-removed comment]